# Doesn't show 64-bit options in VirtualBox after doing everything

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, 32-vs-64-bit

Here is everything straight.

1. My OS is 32-bit Window 7 Home Basic.
2. My processor is Intel Pentium P6200, which is 64-bit capable.
3. I have VirtualBox 5.0.4 installed.
4. I have the ISO file of Ubuntu 14.04.3 LST, downloaded via torrent.
5. Intel Virtualization Technology is enabled in the BIOS (there it says 'Intel Virtual Technology').
6. The I/o APIC is on too.
7. My laptop is Lenovo G560

But the New Virtual Machine window doesn't give a 64-bit option for any OS of any company. Don't start telling me to go to Settings then System then Acceleration because it is greyed out. I don't have Hyper-V (I at least don't have seen anything with that name). Where exactly is the problem? Is it the BIOS? Is it the host OS being 32-bit? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @duDE He has windows 7 64-bit, I have 32-bit. I have latest BIOS. And everyone is going on and on about Hyper-V, which I don't have.

Comment: The host OS doesn't matter, can be 32 or 64 bit. I would take a look at http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2014/11/virtualbox-showing-32-bit-guest-versions-64-bit-host-os/, it's a good one :)

Comment: @duDE Thanks, but i have been there already. As I said everyone is going about hyper-v which I don't have.Plus, it doesn't feel funny when it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Your hardware ( i.e. the processor ) does not support running a 64-bit operating system because it does not have support for the required x86 extensions that make that possible. As per the answer to the duplicate question.  You need to enable `VT-d` and `Intel Visualization Technology` and your processor does not support `VT-d` per the specification document provided by Intel.

Comment: @Ramhound Windows Experience Index's Assessment chart says that my computer is 64-bit capable. It's not like I don't trust you, but please send me a link to the documentation you are talking about. Plus, aren't Vt-d and Intel Virtualization Technology the same.

Comment: @VaradMahashabde - I suppose your confusion stems from the fact, my comment, should have indicated you cannot run a guest 64-bit operating system from within the host operating system.  No; `Vt-d` and `Intel Virtualization Technology`, are not one in the same.  But that doesn't matter your processor does not appear to support any of the Virtualization extensions.  With all that said, the last sentence makes it clear, what I actually meant.  As for the documentation, it is on Intel's website, just do a Google search for your processor and you will find it.

Comment: @Ramhound What about Windows saying that my computer is 64-bit capable?

Comment: @VaradMahashabde - Yes;  You can install a 64-bit installation of Windows as the host operating system.  What you cannot do is use a non-existent visualization technology in order to install a 64-bit guest operating system on a 32-bit host operating system.  **Which is what you indicated you wanted to do.**  [Intel Pentium P6200](http://ark.intel.com/products/50176/Intel-Pentium-Processor-P6200-3M-Cache-2_13-GHz).  Your CPU does not support the required CPU virtualization extensions required to run a 64-bit operating system from within a 32-bit operating system.

Comment: @Ramhound So, if my Windows 7 were 64-bit, would I have been able to run it? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: No; your hardware does not support running a 64-bit OS within a virtual machine

Comment: @Ramhound Please answer the question so that I can accept it and the question can be closed.

Comment: @VaradMahashabde - The question was closed 7 days ago.  Even if I wanted to answer the question I couldn't.